# how to write mapreduce in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, mapreduce, data-processing

I have some data like

```
00 13
00 15
01 12
02 52
02 12
```

and how can get the mr result

```
00 28
01 12
02 64
```

I'm novice at bash, any advice would be appreciated! thx

Comment: `awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i])' file`

Comment: take a look here for inspiration: https://github.com/erikfrey/bashreduce

Comment: thanks for your reply.@123 it seems have syntax error. @Marcel Steinbach it's a very handsome tool, but I just want use basic bash or awk.

Comment: So does the code in @123's comment do what you want or not? If not, edit your question to explain your requirements better. Do not assume the awk experts reading this have any clue what `mapreduce` is or would be willing to spend their time (as opposed to you spending your time) researching beyond what you tell us in your question.

Comment: @123 code is missing the end curly brace before the closing single quote, easy to fix.

Comment: @EdMorton To be fair though my command is missing the final `}` so would have failed.

Comment: @123 if the OP can't read the syntax error and fix THAT problem then abandon all hope... :-).

Comment: thanks @Ed Morton 's advice. beginners will not will always be new. I spent the whole day to make sense of 123 's anwser, it's quite a magic. thank all you guy's reply.

Comment: Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be doing any text processing in UNIX or any other environment where you could have/get awk.

Answer (score 4):

Answer from [@123's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767682/how-to-write-mapreduce-in-shell#comment59208873_35767682):

```
 awk 'NF { a[$1] += $2 } END { for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' file
```

This has two parts.  First, as you parse the file, every line with one or more fields will increment associative array `a[]` at index `$1` (the value of the first column on the line) with `$2` (the value of the second column on the line).  This stores all of your data, adding as it finds duplicates.

Once the file is fully parsed, the `END` stanza triggers and you loop for each item `i` within `a[]`.  When given multiple arguments, `print` will separate them with the output field separator (`OFS`, which defaults to a space: ), so this prints the array index `i`, a space, then the sum of all the input's rows matching that index (`a[i]`).

I added the `NF` test as a safety so that blank rows are ignored.  (Zero fields means `NF` is zero, and when evaluated as a boolean, zero is false, so the condition is not met and nothing is run for that line.)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the question didn't have a direct answer - even though I agree that the awk solution is much more fun than the one I'm giving here. However I did want to offer the code in Bash as it's not very sophisticated and someone might want to modify it.

The input file should be a  whitespace seperated list of key-value pairs.

```
#/usr/bin/bash

declare -A HASHMAP

while IFS= read -r line
do
  export $(printf "KEY=%s VALUE=%s" $(echo "$line"))
  HASHMAP["$KEY"]=$((${HASHMAP["$KEY"]} + $VALUE))
done < input_file

for KEY in "${!HASHMAP[@]}"
do
    echo "$KEY ${HASHMAP[$KEY]}"
done
```